# Can't rename (refactor) names in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Can't refactor variables from `_someName` to `someName` (delete `_`).
Even when I rename all variable like from `_someName` to `anotherName` it come out like `_anotherName`. Can't get rid of `"_"`. Does it require some settings?
I use TypeScript language, last version of WebStorm, MacOS X. With variables without `_` everything is okay.

```js
export class Vector2 {
    protected _top: number;
    protected _left: number;

    public constructor(top: number, left: number) {
        this._top = top;
        this._left = left;
    }

    public equals(otherVector: Vector2): boolean {
        if (this.getTop() === otherVector.getTop() && this.getLeft() === otherVector.getLeft())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public getTop(): number {
        return this._top;
    }

    public setTop(value: number) {
        this._top = value;
    }

    public getLeft(): number {
        return this._left;
    }

    public setLeft(value: number) {
        this._left = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Please provide code snippet that can be used to recreate the issue

Comment: @lena added the code

Comment: try removing `_` from *Field prefix* in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Code generation**

Comment: @lena this helped. Thank you, Lena. Could you post it as an answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try removing `_` from **Field prefix:** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript | Code generation** - this should help